# Why do these identical (except whitespace) javaScript functions return different results

Tags: javascript

I was trying this simple [freecodecamp.org exercise](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures/check-if-an-object-has-a-property), and was running into a problem with my solution.

What I can't work out is why these two functions return different results:

```
let someArray = {
  Person: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  }
};


function works(obj) {
  return ('Person' in obj); 
}

console.log("works returns:" + works(someArray));

function doesNotWork(obj) {
  return  
    ('Person' in obj); 
}

console.log("doesNotWork returns:" + doesNotWork(someArray));
```

The results of running this on node.exe v10.8.0
[image: results of execution]

Why is the second function returning undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You get `undefined` because there is a new line after `return` so it return `undefined` from `doesNotWork` function. Put that in a same line and it works:

```js
let someArray = {
  Person: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  }
};

function works(obj) {
  return ('Person' in obj);
}

console.log("works returns:" + works(someArray));

function doesNotWork(obj) {
  //should be in a same line
  return ('Person' in obj);
}

console.log("doesNotWork returns:" + doesNotWork(someArray));
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that (i.e. the other function). I'm asking why the behaviour is like that.

Comment: @PreetSangha because `return` keyword will return value which is a immediate successor. In your case it was a new line.

Comment: Thanks the dupe explained it all.